# Is it a bug or intentional behaviour that the "timeout" command aborts when you maximize the window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe, timeout

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a `test.bat` file with `timeout /T 60` as its only contents.
2. Run it.
3. Maximize its (`cmd.exe`) window.

It now immediately aborts and closes itself. At least for me.

And yes, I know about the `/NOBREAK` flag, which I now use and which does prevent not only keypresses but also the maximization bug (?), but I still wish to know why this happens.

I'm not sure why I care specifically about this since I keep finding show-stopping, serious bugs constantly while trying to use Windows, but somehow this seems like a "core utility" and it really bothers me that it just kills the window when you maximize it. It's not mentioned in the `timeout /?` output, which purely speaks of keypresses.

Note: This does NOT happen if you open a cmd.exe and just type the command into it. It has to be in a .bat file for this to occur.

Comment: It keeps running on my Windows 10 Pro machine. What Show Stopping bugs do you have. Windows 10 Pro has be running well for me for five years now.

Comment: Your note is incorrect. I can launch cmd, type in the command and it breaks just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is both a bug and a feature.

timeout was designed for earlier versions of windows. When you resize the window, the command is also aborted. The reason is that when you resize the window, the window's internal dimensions also change, which triggers a keyboard reset if you will, which causes timeout to register a keypress that isn't actually there.

It also happens in the cmd window from Windows Terminal.

Its suffice to say, this should not happen and likely in windows 7 and earlier, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```batch-file
Windows 10 Pro x64
Windows 7 Starter x86  ⁄⁄ system does not support full-screen mode
```

Why not try to send this command to your `con:` device?

```batch-file
<con: rem./ & timeout /t 60 /nobreak
```

**Obs.:** This also works to **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>** in Windows 10 Pro

---

- Also, check your settings:

[image: Windows 10 Pro]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use powershell for safe delay:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "& {[system.threading.thread]::sleep(60000)}"
```

Use this command in batch file.

Answer (score 0):

No noticed issue, possibly it's your device period. Try downloading the new Microsoft terminal other recently modified commands like that one work way better there and hope this helps.

So if You have a problem with this too this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Same here... maximizing a TIMEOUTed command-line-window kills it... using several  different Win10-systems.

**LPChip** appears to be right to me according to my observations about maximizing triggering a keyboard reset thus triggering a keyboard-input thus triggering the waiting TIMEOUT.

Verify:

Create a batch no. 1 similar to the mentioned one above:

```
@echo off
echo TIMEOUT 1:
echo Batch ends after this timeout.
echo Try to maximize this window... what happens?
timeout /T 20
rem END
```

Following **LPChip**, the batch should continue running after maximizing... if there was any further code. Nothing easier than that to check...

Create a batch no. 2 (or extend 1st one) an see what happens:

```
@echo off
echo TIMEOUT 1:
echo Batch does NOT end after this timeout... there will be another timeout.
echo Try to maximize this window... what happens?
timeout /T 20

echo TIMEOUT 2:
echo Batch ends after this timeout.
echo Try to maximize this window... what happens?
timeout /T 20
rem END
```

In my case(s), maximizing the command-window while the first TIMOUT is still running, it immediately jumps to the next code-lines.